# for_each in terraform nested block

Tags: terraform, pagerduty

I've searched quite a bit and don't think I've found the answer I really need. I'm trying to loop through a nested block and am successful in doing this if all of the attributes are on the same root object. This is great if I want to loop over the entire set of attributes. However this situation is a bit different. I need to loop over an entire set of attributes and also a sub-set.

In this Terragrunt example, you can see the desired inputs since we want to loop over the escalation policy entirely as well as loop the rule and its targets so that we can create many escalation policies with many rules/targets in them.

```
  /// PagerDuty Escalation Policies

  create_escalation_policy = true
  escalation_policies = [
    {
    name        = "TEST Engineering Escalation 1"
    description = "My TEST engineering escalation policy 1"
    teams       = ["111N1CV"]
    num_loops   = 2
    rule = [
      {
      escalation_delay_in_minutes = 15
      target = {
        type = "user_reference"
        id   = "ABCB8F3"
        }
      },
      {
      escalation_delay_in_minutes = 15
      target = {
        type = "user_reference"
        id   = "NBCB1A1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

However, after quite a bit of trial and error, I'm able to loop over the entire escalation policy but not if we have values inside of `rule = {` which returns a generic error that Terraform can't find those attributes in the object which I have confirmed is the root object instead of the nested one. This was validated by simply moving those attributes out to the root of the object input block.

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 121, in resource "pagerduty_escalation_policy" "this":
│  121:         id   = rule.value.id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ rule.value is object with 5 attributes
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
```

For reference, here is the variable for var.escalation_policies

```
variable "escalation_policies" {
  description = "A list of escalation policies and rules for a given PagerDuty service."
  type        = any
}
```

and the resource

```
resource "pagerduty_escalation_policy" "this" {
  for_each = { 
    for key in var.escalation_policies : key.name => {
      name                        = key.name
      description                 = key.description
      num_loops                   = key.num_loops
      teams                       = key.teams
    }
    if var.create_escalation_policy == true 
  }
  name        = each.value.name
  description = each.value.description
  num_loops   = each.value.num_loops
  teams       = each.value.teams
  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = {
      for k, v in var.escalation_policies : k => v }
    content {
      escalation_delay_in_minutes = rule.value.escalation_delay_in_minutes
      target {
        type = rule.value.type
        id   = rule.value.id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current example the `dynamic "rule"` block has a `for` expression that isn't really doing anything useful:

```
{ for k, v in var.escalation_policies : k => v }
```

This expression is strange in two ways:

- Taking the expression alone, it's unusual to project `k, v` directly to `k => v` because that doesn't really change anything about the key or the value. Since your source `var.escalation_policies` is a list rather than a map this *is* changing the data type of the result and making Terraform convert the integer indices to strings instead, but otherwise the elements are the same as `var.escalation_policies`.
- Considering the *context*, this is also unusual because it's repeating the nested block based on the same collection as the containing resource: there will be one `pagerduty_escalation_policy.this` instance per `var.escalation_policy` element and then each one will have one nested `rule` block for each of your escalation policies.

To get a useful result the `for_each` in your `dynamic` block should use a different collection as the basis for its repetition. I think in your case you're intending to use the nested lists inside the `rule` attributes of each of your policies, but your outermost `for_each` expression doesn't include the rules so you'll first need to update that:

```
resource "pagerduty_escalation_policy" "this" {
  for_each = { 
    for policy in var.escalation_policies : policy.name => {
      name                        = policy.name
      description                 = policy.description
      num_loops                   = policy.num_loops
      teams                       = policy.teams
      rules                       = policy.rule
    }
    if var.create_escalation_policy == true 
  }
  # ...
}
```

This means that `each.value` will now include an additional attribute `rules` which has the same value as the corresponding attribute in each element of `var.escalation_policies`.

You can then refer to that `rules` attribute in your `dynamic` block:

```
  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = each.value.rules
    content {
      escalation_delay_in_minutes = rule.value.escalation_delay_in_minutes
      target {
        type = rule.value.target.type
        id   = rule.value.target.id
      }
    }
  }
```

This tells Terraform to generate a dynamic `rule` block for each element of `each.value.rules`, which is the `rules` attribute for the current policy.

Inside the `content` block `rule.value` is the current `rule` object, so you can refer to attributes like `escalation_delay_in_minutes` and `target` from that object.

Comment: Thank you for the very succinct and clear explanation as to what is actually happening under the hood and why the current approach wasn't valid. Your suggestion with `rules = policy.rules` is exactly the missing link I was hunting for. I just tested this change and it works as expected. Thank you many times over.

Answer (score 2):

`id` is a key within the `target` object and not within `rule`:

```
id = rule.value.target.id
```

Note also that a `for` expression which iterates through key-value pairs within a map and outputs the exact same structure is extraneous and can be removed for efficiency and readability:

```
dynamic "rule" {
  for_each = var.escalation_policies
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew enough that the for_each here was worthless but wasn't completely sure what it should be and clearly didn't fully grasp what was happening under the hood. This part is helpful.